# What should I do if "Retirement Plan" is not checked on my W-2 but should be?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, form-w-2

I received my W-2 from my employer recently and I noticed that the box "Retirement Plan" is not checked. This was checked for the previous years and I have made no changes to the retirement plan.

I contacted the payroll personnel and I was told that even though it should be checked it shouldn't be an issue and I should just keep filing my taxes as my W-2 says (Retirement plan unchecked). I do not believe that this will effect my taxes this year because I didn't contribute to a traditional IRA.

I'm just wondering if it's really OK to file my taxes with this W-2 even though I know the box should be checked. Could this hurt me in the long run?

Comment: do the rest of the numbers on the W-2 match your last paycheck?

Comment: Do you contribute to a tax-advantaged retirement plan?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep everything except this portion seems correct.

Comment: @RonJohn I do not believe I do. What is a tax-advantaged retirement plan?

Comment: @Programmer tax-advantaged plan: a 401K/403B/457 or the TSP for federal workers.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep Oh ok, then it's not a tax-advantaged plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File your taxes with the W-2 that you have. If you have no reason to doubt the content of the rest of the form, there is no reason not to file with what you have.  It is possible that the tax rules have changed this year which might affect whether or not that box gets checked.

If this is the only question you have about your taxes for this year, it is unlikely that your W-2 is incorrect, and if your income is mostly from this particular job (besides interest income, etc), it is also unlikely to have a major effect on your return.